# How to automatically select anchor when scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor, vertical-scrolling

I will try to explain as clearly as I can.

I have a sidebar with, for example, 3 items. Each item is a link to an anchor in the page. I use the scrollTo function to have a smooth scrolling when I click on an item. It works great.

But what I want now is that when I scroll, to go for example to the anchor 3, the current anchor which is shown while scrolling will be selected automatically. Clear ?

For example : the item 1 is selected. I start scrolling and i arrive to the anchor 2. Automatically, the item 2 is selected and the item 1 is going to a not selected state.

I continue scrolling and I arrive the anchor 3. The item 2 is going to the not selected state and the item 3 is automatically selected.

So the items states automacally change by scrolling and not only y clicking on the item.

Is there a smart way to do that ?

Thanks by advance.

Bastien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap has an implementation:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy

Also, jQuery waypoints provides sufficient functionality:
http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: yes I did a link to waypoints in my comment. Thanks for the answer

Comment: I did this using Bootstrap scrollspy, but I'm now thinking about switching to Waypoints. With Bootstrap, the thing gets messed up when I resize my browser, or when a twitter widget loads after the spyscroll has loaded and changes the height of the site. There are fixes for the bootstrap spyscroll (refresh when window size changes etc.) but spyscroll seems more robust. What do you think if you have tried them both?

Answer (score 0):

check out this plugin: http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/

Comment: thanks but I found this one which is exactly what I want ! :) http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: Just awesome. I just checked the examples and wow ! You can do amazing things with it. Happy to share this find.